# Binding buttons to keyboard buttons and sounds

Tags: javascript, c, visual-c++, exe

I'm a noob developer using Microsoft Visuals 2015 and I was working on a software but got in a bit of a jam, you can view it in the screenshot. What I want to do is bind the letter keys to the letters on the keyboard. So if I press <kbd>Q</kbd> on my keyboard for example, it should press the `Q` button on my software. same with the num buttons on the right. I'd also like to add a sound for each key and the option to set which sound you want to bind to which key without having to open Microsoft visual (if that's possible). I would gladly appreciate a response. This is the first software I'm developing, and if it works, I will definitely go further in developing it.

[image: view image]

Comment: You tagged this with `javascript`, `c`, and `visual-c++`, which doesn't seem to make sense (especially `javascript`).

Answer (score 1):

I dont know which languge you are going to use but on you can use  "windows key hook" if you want to do it in every time and everywhere when your program works.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644959(v=vs.85).aspx
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644960(v=vs.85).aspx